# How to make a View looks like it is being selected programmatically, if background is ?android:attr/selectableItemBackground (ListView in AlertDialog)

Tags: android

I pretty like the selector behavior generated in navigation drawer.

[image]

1. It has ripple effect.
2. Its `ImageView` and `TextView` has proper color, when being selected.

---

In my dialog, I try to achieve the same effect, by using the following layout.

### label_array_adapter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:paddingStart="24dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="?attr/labelIconSelector" />

    <TextView
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="?attr/labelTextViewColorSelector" />
</LinearLayout>
```

### labelIconSelector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_label_white_24dp"
            android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryBrown" />
    </item>

    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_label_white_24dp"
            android:tint="#ff757575" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

### labelTextViewColorSelector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/colorPrimaryBrown" />
    <item android:color="@color/primaryTextColorLight" />
</selector>
```

In my `ArrayAdapter`, I try to programmatically select the 1st item via `view.setSelected(true)`

```
public class LabelArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TabInfo> {
    private static class ViewHolder {
        public final ImageView imageView;
        public final TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            textView = view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);

            Utils.setCustomTypeFace(textView, Utils.ROBOTO_REGULAR_TYPE_FACE);
        }
    }

    public LabelArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, List<TabInfo> tabInfos) {
        super(context, R.layout.label_array_adapter, tabInfos);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext());
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.label_array_adapter, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);

            // Not sure why this is required.
            view.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Utils.dpToPixel(48)));
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        TabInfo tabInfo = getItem(position);
        if (tabInfo == null) {
            holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.textView.setText("(No label)");
        } else {
            holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.textView.setText(tabInfo.getName());
        }

        if (position == 0) {
            view.setSelected(true);
        } else {
            view.setSelected(false);
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

---

This is how I try to show `Dialog` via `DialogFragment`.

```
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle("Move to")
            .setAdapter(new LabelArrayAdapter(this.getContext(), customTabInfos), (dialog, which) -> {

            })
            .create();
```

---

However, it doesn't work as you can see in the following screenshot. The 1st item doesn't look like it is being selected.

[image]

May I know, is there anything I had missed out?

*How to make a View looks like it is being selected programmatically, if its background is ?android:attr/selectableItemBackground  (ListView in AlertDialog)*

---

### Update

Using

```
alertDialog.getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
alertDialog.getListView().setSelection(position);
```

wouldn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using a layer list drawable as the background for the view group that represents the item being selected.

First, for API 21+, we define a layer list drawable that displays the selected color when the item is selected. A call to `View#setSelected()` must be made for this to have an effect.

**layer_list.xml (v21)**

*`color/selected` is `#2000ffe5` for the demos.*

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <selector>
            <item
                android:drawable="@color/selected"
                android:state_selected="true" />
        </selector>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/selectableBackground"
        android:drawable="?android:selectableItemBackground" />
</layer-list>
```

[image]

For API < 21, we cannot use `android:drawable="?android:selectableItemBackground"` in the layer list, so we will fall back to an alternate but similar visual cue.

**layer_list < API 21**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <selector android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">
            <item
                android:drawable="@color/selected"
                android:state_pressed="false"
                android:state_selected="true" />
            <item
                android:drawable="@color/selectable_background"
                android:state_pressed="true" />
        </selector>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

Comment: My question is regarding how to make an item has visualized selected UI, programmatically, for ListView in AlertDialog.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng Apply the layer list to the `LinearLayout` of `label_array_adapter.xml` as the background instead of `?android:attr/selectableItemBackground`. Does that not work?